# TensorFlow : how to fix createtflitesimdmodule of tflite returning empty buffers

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js

i dont understand the problem from where its coming but when i call createtflitesimdmodule from the tflite.simd file it return empty buffers but before it was working as expected and when i call this function tflite._getModelBufferMemoryOffset() return 0, what is the missing thing, is there any declaration to do before.

```
import createTFLiteSIMDModule from './tflite/tflite-simd.js';
const tflite = await createTFLiteSIMDModule();
const modelBufferOffset = tflite._getModelBufferMemoryOffset();
```

this is the result of console.log(tflite)
[image]

Comment: Could you include a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code? :)

Comment: i edited the issue including the example, thank you

Comment: Are you following some sort of tutorial or borrowing code from github? If so could you share a link to it here as as `tflite-simd.js` isn't an official tensorflow.js module

Comment: I think this [file](https://github.com/Volcomix/virtual-background/blob/main/src/core/hooks/useTFLite.ts) might show how to instantiate the tflite model

Comment: yeah that may work for typescript , i'm using only js , i found the solution by updating the files https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/react/features/stream-effects/virtual-background/vendor/tflite/tflite-simd.js , thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you, but I'm glad you found the solution you needed! If you would be so kind, could you put your solution and an explanation of it in an answer to your own question so that others may refer to it as well? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Providing solution here for the benefit of the community.

The issue was resolved by updating the files, Ref [link](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/react/features/stream-effects/virtual-background/vendor/tflite/tflite-simd.js).